# Laravel 7.x Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: jquery, vue.js, laravel-7

I am using Larave 7.x version. To test JQuery, I put the following Code at the end inside body tag in welcome.blade.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert('JQuery is ready!');
    });
</script>
```

It throws the following error...

**Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at ...**

Then I deleted `deffer` from the script.

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

Now JQuery is Ok. But it throws the following error...

**[Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #app**

The matter is that, I can use either **JQuery** or **Vue** but not the both.

Is there any way to use both JQuery and Vue at the same time?

Comment: jQuery should not be necessary or desirable if you're using vue. Stick to one consistent way of doing things in your JavaScript

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution like this...

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        // Your jquery code            
        alert('JQuery is ready!');            
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `JQuery is ready`... except that this is all standard JavaScript, there's no jQuery here.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error, but adding this line to your app.js should fix it:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having exactly the same issue, my solution was to create a new js file (test.js) with the code using jQuery, added to webpack.mix.js, and imported on welcome.blade.php:

welcome.blade.php

```
<header
    <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
    <script src="{{ mix('js/test.js') }}" defer></script>
</header
```

webpack.mix.blade

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .js("resources/js/test.js", "public/js")
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .sourceMaps();
```

test.js

```
$(() => {
    alert('JQuery is ready!');
})
```